# Apps do not exist on moving them to SD card on Tab-1030

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, app2sd, internal-sd

I have a Tab-1030 Android tablet (Tab-1030) with Android 4.0.4

Whatever apps I move into the SD Card get deleted. The first occurrence happened when for some reason my tablet couldn't connect to the wi-fi and I couldn't access Google Play.

After that I restarted my tablet (it also took longer than usual to start up again) and when I tapped on one of my games, it announced that the app didn't exist. Looking deeper into it, all the apps (5 of them) that I moved into the SD card had no data. They were deleted!

The blank apps showed that they had cached data which was a lifesaver because after I re-downloaded the apps some memory of what I had done was saved.

From there I tried to not move any important apps to the SD card, but a few months later the same thing happened. This time it was because I mounted my phone's microSD card (16 GB). After I unmounted the microSD card, the few apps that I moved to the SD card had again been deleted.

Can someone, anyone help me out and explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much answered yourself: you move your apps to your SD card, then you unmount your SD card.

No SD card -> the apps in it are not there anymore -> Android considers they have been deleted.

Comment: But the thing is that I'm moving them to the internal SD Card. And whenever I mount a microSD card or use USB the apps that were in the devices internal sd card are delete. The cached data is still there but the app isn't.

Comment: @Marty: Well, you didn't said you moved to the internal SD Card. But on recent devices, the internal SD Card storage is shared between the SD Card content, and the apps (also system, etc...) so moving apps to the internal SD Card should change nothing to your storage space and just make your system less stable.